# Конвертировние времени из int в локальное время

Tags: cocoa, время, objective-c, дата

Добрый день! 
Имеется дата, которую генерирует сервер и отдает int такого формата 1358600146517
Нужно получить время с учетом локального часового пояса такого формата HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сервер отдает время в Unix timestamp, то используйте метод `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` класса  `NSDate` (http://osxdev.ru/blog/objective-c/111.html):

```
time_t server_time = ....;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:server_time];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Потом для форматирования можете использовать NSDateFormatter

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss zzz" ];

NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); //  2013.01.18 19:29:58 GMT+07:00
```

Comment: dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 работает отлично, осталось разобратся как GMT поменять на локальный

Comment: используйте NSNumberFormatter, он учитывает текущую локаль и временную зону

Comment: Упс по началу думал нормально оказалось не совсем, время совершенно радномное получается.
на стороне сервер генерить java функцией  Data().getTime()

Comment: Тогда так 

NSTimeInterval unix_time = server_time / 1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unix_time];

Data().getTime() - возвращает время в миллисекундах от начала Unix эпохи

Comment: +1 за телепатию насчёт формата времени.

Comment: все отлично, только заместо time_t использую double, теперь все корректно! всем спасибо )